# IntelliJ 15 reorders imports while optimizing

Tags: intellij-idea, automated-refactoring

When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> in IntelliJ it removes unused imports but also reorder imports. This messes up code reviews. How do I prevent it from reordering imports?

Comment: can you give an example why it seems "messed up" for code reviews? background: I'm quite satisfied of the way IJ does optimize imports.

Comment: You don't. It sorts imports alphabetically. If you run optimize imports on your entire project once, they will be sorted, and will remain sorted. Sorting imports helps avoid merge conflicts (otherwise all new imports are added to the end of the import list, which is guaranteed to cause a conflict if two developers add imports in the same file).

Comment: I have the same problem regularly,  but, I think,  it's because most of my colleagues use eclipse and eclipse optimize imports differently.

Comment: Yes the imports are already ordered in a particular way in the code. By hitting optimize it changes the order and the code review tool of course marks it as code changes.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for an automated way to delete unused imports that doesn't reorder the existing imports, you could instead use the **Delete unnecessary imports** feature of the IntelliJ Inspector. 
[image]

First you have to have the **Unused Import** inspection enabled in the *Inspections* preferences (Preferences, Editor, Inspections, Imports). 
[image]

Then run the *Inspector* on your current file (Analyze, Inspect Code). I have a keyboard shortcut mapped to that. 
[image]

After the inspection completes, expand **Unused import**, right click on your class, and choose **Delete unnecessary imports**.
[image]

Also make sure you have the **Optimize imports on the fly** preference disabled (Preferences, General, Auto Import)
[image]

Comment: That works, thanks. I'd really like a less clunky way of doing it though. A checkbox that toggles sorting would be perfect.

Comment: Instead of right-clicking on the problem you can Alt+Enter->Enter to apply the quick fix. Combined with arrow keys for navigating to the next item, this is the least clunky way I found, unfortunately.